# Shunting-Yard Algorithm C++ Not Passing Correctly Between Methods?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, shunting-yard

I am tasked with writing a Shunting-Yard algorithm for use in my final project (a calculator). I have written the program the way that makes sense to me, however, I am not getting any output when calling the main algorithm function (toRPN). I believe this is an issue with passing the values between parse and toRPN because I have tested parse directly within main and it works fine, but when I try to do a print test in the toRPN function, it prints nothing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

**Header:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SHUNTING_YARD_ALGORITHM_SHUNTINGYARD_H
#define SHUNTING_YARD_ALGORITHM_SHUNTINGYARD_H


class ShuntingYard {
public:
    stack <string> stack;
    vector <string> tokens;
    queue <string> outputList;
    vector <char> operators;
    vector <int> precedence;
    vector <char> associativity;
    ShuntingYard ();
    bool hasOnlyDigits(const string s);
    int getPrecedence(const string s);
    int getAssociativity(const char c);
    vector<string> parse(const string input) const;
    string mainAlgorithm(const string);
};

#endif //SHUNTING_YARD_ALGORITHM_SHUNTINGYARD_H
```

**cpp:**

```
#include "ShuntingYard.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

stack <string> stack1;
queue <string> outputList;
vector <string> operators;
vector <int> precedence;
vector <char> associativity;

ShuntingYard::ShuntingYard () = default;

bool hasOnlyDigits(const string s){
    return s.find_first_not_of( "0123456789" ) == string::npos;
}

int getPrecedence(const string s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < operators.size(); i++) {
        if (s ==  operators[i])
            return precedence[i];
    }
}
char getAssociativity(const string s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < operators.size(); i++) {
        if (s == operators[i])
            return associativity[i];
    }
}

vector<string> parse(const string input) {
// Parses the string by white space
    istringstream ss(input);
    vector <string> tokenVector;

    // Fill vector with ss
    for (string input; ss >> input;) {
        tokenVector.push_back(input);
    }
    return tokenVector;
}


string toRPN(const string s) {

    // Delimit string by white space and store in vector
    vector <string> tokens = parse(s);

    // Test print
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i ++)
        cout << tokens[i];

    //Change "rt" to "$" to be easily accessed
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i ++) {
        if (tokens[i] == "rt")
            tokens[i] = "$";
    }

    // Stores operators and their precedence/associativity to vectors using same index
    operators.push_back("+"); precedence.push_back(2); associativity.push_back('L');
    operators.push_back("-"); precedence.push_back(2); associativity.push_back('L');
    operators.push_back("/"); precedence.push_back(3); associativity.push_back('L');
    operators.push_back("*"); precedence.push_back(3); associativity.push_back('L');
    operators.push_back("^"); precedence.push_back(4); associativity.push_back('R');
    operators.push_back("$"); precedence.push_back(4); associativity.push_back('R');


    // Shunting-Yard logic
    while (tokens.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
            if (hasOnlyDigits(tokens[i]))
            outputList.push(tokens[i]);
            if ( find(operators.begin(), operators.end(), tokens[i]) != operators.end()) {
                while (getPrecedence(stack1.top()) > getPrecedence(tokens[i]) || (getPrecedence(stack1.top()) == getPrecedence(tokens[i]) &&
                getAssociativity(tokens[i]) == 'L') && stack1.top() != "(") {
                    outputList.push(stack1.top());
                    stack1.pop();
                    stack1.push(tokens[i]);
                }
            }
            if (tokens[i] == "(")
                stack1.push(tokens[i]);
            if (tokens[i] == ")")
                while(!stack1.empty() && stack1.top() != "(") {
                    outputList.push(stack1.top());
                    stack1.pop();
                }
                stack1.pop();
        }
            if (tokens.size() == 0) {
                while(!stack1.empty()) {
                    outputList.push(stack1.top());
                    stack1.pop();
                }
            }
    }

    // Replaces values with "$" back to "rt"
    string str;
    while (!outputList.empty()) {
        if (outputList.front() == "$") {
            str.insert(0,"rt");
            outputList.pop();
        }
        else {
            str.insert(0, (outputList.front()));
            outputList.pop();
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    string s1 = "3 + 4";
    cout << toRPN(s1);
}
```

Update:

I have narrowed the issue down to the following while loop:

```
while (getPrecedence(stack1.top()) > getPrecedence(tokens[i]) || (getPrecedence(stack1.top()) == getPrecedence(tokens[i]) &&
                getAssociativity(tokens[i]) == 'L') && stack1.top() != "(") {
                    outputList.push(stack1.top());
                    stack1.pop();
                    stack1.push(tokens[i]);
                }
```

The line getPrecedence(stack1.top() > getPrecedence(tokens[I]) is the issue. In particular, running getPrecedence on the stack1.top(). This function basically takes in a string and compares it to the vector holding all of the operators that are stored. When it finds the index, it returns the precedence at that index (they are set up with all the indices in order). I don't see why I can't call this function in this way. The stack1.top() will just give a string which would be passed through and compared. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: May the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) be with you.

Comment: `stack <string> stack;` how does this ever compile?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  It's especially pernicious in header files, as you now inflict the problem on every source file that includes the header!

Comment: Actually, it threw an ambiguity error and wouldn't compile with stack <string> stack. I had updated it in the cpp to stack1, but forgot to in the header. Fixed that now, thanks. And okay, I'll look into not using the namespace std.

Comment: You appear to be calling `pop` on an empty stack, which I believe is Undefined Behavior, but I'd have to do some reverse-engineering to figure out where the actual bug is.

Comment: @Beta That could be. However, I have a test print set up in the toRPN function that isn't outputting anything at all, when it should be parsing the string by white space and storing it into the tokens vector. That comes before any of the stack or queue stuff.

Comment: There is stack stuff *in* `toRPN`. In particular, a `stack1.pop();` in the "Shunting-Yard logic".

Comment: @Beta Correct, but wouldn't it still print my test before running into any issues with that? I am referring to the second block of toRPN, where I print the vector of strings. I am trying to see if it gets the correct output from the parse function and it appears that it isn't.

Comment: Try putting `<< endl` on the end of that line. Without it, `cout` stores the characters in a buffer. Then the program crashes before they get to the screen.

Comment: @Beta Wow, thanks so much! The test print works now! So now I know the string is getting tokenized and placed in the vector, but I am unsure why the algorithm isn't performing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There were a few things going one, but the main one which was haunting the program was that I was popping things off the stack when I shouldn't, resulting in the stack being empty, so it would never get into

```
while (getPrecedence(stack1.top()) > getPrecedence(tokens[i]) || (getPrecedence(stack1.top()) == getPrecedence(tokens[i]) &&
                getAssociativity(tokens[i]) == 'L') && stack1.top() != "(")
```